# PGF/TikZ Object-Oriented Programming Scope Issue

Tags: tikz-pgf, scoping

I'm experimenting with the PGF/TikZ Object-Oriented Programming functionality and have encountered what appears to be a scoping issue that I do not understand. I have provided a minimum example of the issue below.

In this example, I am creating a class called Value that stores data. I am then performing an add operation on two of these Values and creating a new Value object in the process. The add operation takes as input two Values and the desired name of the output Value.

This works as expected when the two Values are created from scratch but not when one of the inputs to the add operation is itself the output of a previous add operation the add operation updates the value of the input Value, which it shouldn't do.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgfmodule{oo}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}

\pgfooclass{Value}{
    \attribute data;

    \method Value(#1) {
        \pgfooset{data}{#1}
    }

    \method getdata(#1) {
        \pgfooget{data}{#1}
    }

    \method setdata(#1) {
        \pgfooset{data}{#1}
    }

    \method show() {
        \pgfooget{data}\tempdata
        \pgfoothis.get id(\tempid)
        Value(data: \tempdata)
    }
}

% Define the add function outside the class
\def\addValues(#1,#2,#3) { 
    Performing Add Operation:
    % Get  data
    #1.getdata(\selfdata)
    #2.getdata(\otherdata)

    % Compute the new data
    \FPeval\newdata{\selfdata + \otherdata}
    % \selfdata is updated here incorrectly on the second call

    % Create the new Value object with the computed data
    \expandafter\pgfoonew\csname #3\endcsname=new Value(\newdata)
}

\begin{document}

\pgfoonew \x=new Value(5)
x: \x.show() % Value(data: 5)

\pgfoonew \y=new Value(4)
y: \y.show() % Value(data: 4)

\addValues(\x,\y,z) % This works without issue since x and y are created from scratch
z: \z.show() % Value(data: 9.000000000000000000)

\pgfoonew \v=new Value(3) 
v: \v.show() % Value(data: 3)

\addValues(\z,\v,o) % This doesn't work and \z data value is incorrectly updated by the line \FPeval\newdata{\selfdata + \otherdata}
o: \o.show() % Value(data: 12.000000000000000000)

z: \z.show() % Should still show Value(data: 9.000000000000000000) but now Value(data: 12.000000000000000000)

\pgfoonew \k=new Value(20)
k: \k.show() % Value(data: 5)

\pgfoonew \j=new Value(2)
j: \j.show() % Value(data: 4)

\addValues(\k,\j,l)
l: \l.show() % Value(data: 20.000000000000000000) works fine.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Not an answer, but just a comment.  I experimented with the PGF OO stuff many years ago.  Then LaTeX3 came along and I switched to that.  As weird as LaTeX3 is, it is so much more straightforward than PGF's OO stuff.  I think that the design of the PGF OO tries too hard to be "traditional" OO, which means that it sometimes has to fight against TeX.  Whereas LaTeX3 is very much more in harmony with TeX so although it still has oddities, they are much more understandable when viewed in a TeX context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In

```latex
\expandafter\pgfoonew\csname #3\endcsname=new Value(\newdata)
```

you are assigning the value of `#3` as `\newdata`, not the *value* of `\newdata`. Probably the easiest fix is to use `\expanded`:

```latex
\expanded{%
  \noexpand\pgfoonew\expandafter\noexpand\csname #3\endcsname=new Value(\newdata)%
}%
```

Comment: The need to use `\expanded` links to what Andrew says: the OO approach here is anti-pattern for TeX, so for example we can't easily `\expandafter` a sensible number of tokens to get to the value of `\newdata`.